# Add time to HH:mm string

Tags: javascript, string, date

I am currently having a list of time string

```
1: 20:15
2: 20:15
3: 20:15
4: 19:15
5: 20:00
6: 19:15
7: 20:15
8: 20:15
9: 19:00
10: 19:15
11: 20:15
12: 19:00
13: 20:00
14: 20:00 
15: 20:00
16: 20:00
```

since they are not in my local timezone I would like to add 2 hours to every time on the list but I am not sure how to do this with the Date function since I only have access to the hours and minutes rather than the full date.

This might be something simple but to be honest this is my first time using dates in JS.

The Output should look like

```
1: 22:15
2: 22:15
3: 22:15
4: 21:15
5: 22:00
6: 21:15
7: 22:15
8: 22:15
9: 21:00
10: 21:15
11: 22:15
12: 21:00
13: 22:00
14: 22:00 
15: 22:00
16: 22:00
```

I am getting the string from an API so this also has to work for any other list of strings (Format: HH:mm).

Since this is one of my learning projects I would rather enjoy implementing this without an external script.

Comment: When working with dates/time/timezones I *highly* recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com), which supports things like `moment('20:15', 'hh:mm').add(2, 'hours')`.

Comment: This question may help, also using mommentjs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Sorry for not saying this in the question. This is for one of my learning projects so I would rather enjoy implementing this without any external scripts or libraries.

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal momentjs is a over the top for this simple problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably split each time in to hours and minutes, `parseInt` the hours, add 2 and the recombine

```js
let times = ["20:15", "20:15", "20:15", "19:15", "20:00", "19:15", "20:15", "20:15", "19:00", "19:15", "20:15", "19:00", "20:00", "20:00", "20:00", "20:00"];

let updatedTimes = times.map(time => {
  let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');

  // add 2 hours, make sure it's not more than 23
  hours = (parseInt(hours) + 2) % 24;

  return [hours, minutes].join(':');
});

console.log(updatedTimes);
```

Comment: thank you this solved the problem and was also the cleanest solution.

Comment: @K.Kleinvogel Just curious but why did you accept jmcgriz's answer instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Not bothered which answer you pick so long as it helped.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case, it's probably simpler to just split the string and update it that way.

```js
var times = [
"20:15",
"20:15",
"20:15",
"19:15",
"20:00",
"19:15",
"20:15",
"20:15",
"19:00",
"19:15",
"20:15",
"19:00",
"20:00",
"20:00",
"23:00",
"20:00"
]

function add2hours(time){
  let HM = time.split(':'),
    h = parseInt(HM[0]) + 2, m = HM[1]
    
  if(h > 23) h -= 24
    
  return [h, m].join(':')
  
}

console.log(times.map(add2hours))
```